# How to disable Sensor ESLint-based SonarJS?

Tags: sonarqube, eslint, sonarjs

In our environment we already use ESLint to produce json report. Starting from Sonarqube 7.2, SonarJS plugin can import this report file.

But I see in analysis report that some **Sensor ESLint-based SonarJS** also starting. But this one does not understand our React based project sysntax, and trying to do dual work, actualy
Is there any way to disable this sensor?

Answer (score 2):

You should not disable this sensor. Currently SonarJS is gradually migrated from its own parser to espree (ESLint parser). **Sensor ESLint-based SonarJS** runs rules on espree-compalible AST. Currently it's only small subset of rules, but in future entire SonarJS functionality (rules, metrics, highlighting) will be based on it. **Sensor ESLint-based SonarJS** doesn't rely on your eslint configuration, currently it executes only rules activated in SonarQube and having eslint-based implementation.

The right action to make is [to report to SonarJS team](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/new) the problem you have with parsing you React project code.

Comment: It's a valid point that the SonarJS scan is at least in part redundant when using `eslint-plugin-sonarjs`.